# get a list of factors in sympy.factor

Tags: sympy

I'm implementing an algorithm, and in it I need to get factor a polynomial f(x) = p(x)q(x) with p and q relatively prime. I can use, of course, sympy.factor, but I would like to construct a function that returns perhaps a list of factors in a sympy.factor result.

For example,

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
g = sympy.Poly(y**4 + x*y**3 + y**2 + x*y, y)
sympy.factor(g)
```

throws out

```
y*(x + y)*(y**2 + 1)
```

so perhaps I could build a parser that interprets the string and divides it between the parenthesis rendering the list [y, x+y, y * * 2 + 1], but I would like to know: **is there an easier way?**

Comment: How about `g.factor().args` ?

Comment: didn't know about that!, thanks. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `factor_list`, which returns a structured list of the factors. Unfortunately, it looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11775) with this specific polynomail in Python 3. In Python 2, I get

```
In [1]: factor_list(y**4 + x*y**3 + y**2 + x*y, y)
Out[1]:
⎛   ⎡                    ⎛ 2       ⎞⎤⎞
⎝1, ⎣(y, 1), (x + y, 1), ⎝y  + 1, 1⎠⎦⎠
```

The first element is the constant coefficient. The second is a list of `(factor, power)` pairs (the final expression equals `constant * factor**power * ... * factor**power`).

Comment: Moreover, g.factor().args reutrns (y,x) when I pass it the polynomial g(x) = x+y. What does it mean?, how can I interpret g.factor().args more generally. I have another quick question: how can I quickly tell wether a polynomial has a factorization or not in sympy?, thanks, and sorry for all the bothering.

Comment: `.args` splits an expression into its components. `x + y` is an `Add`, so its args are `(x, y)`. See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html. To always split an expression as a product, use `Mul.make_args`.

Comment: To answer your other question, `factor` always returns irreducible factors. So if `factor` returns no factors, then the polynomial is irreducible. You can also use `Poly.is_irredubicle`, which does some simple irreducibility tests before attempting full factorization.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you mind if I send you emails with rising questions or bugs in the rest of my implementation?, I promise not to be a pest.

Comment: It would be better to email the SymPy list, or to ask here. I'm not always responsive on my personal emails.

Comment: I was wondering: if we get the factor list using this method, will it always put the linear factors first? (i.e. is the irreducible part of the polynomial always in the end?)

Comment: @Miguelgondu it looks like they are sorted by the number of terms, not degree. Note that every factor is irreducible (linear factors are also irreducible). If you want a different sorting you should sort them yourself using functions like `total_degree` in the sort key.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution which works for non-polynomial expressions too (like with `g = x*y + sympy.exp(x)*y`), and doesn't break when `factor` can't find any factors (like with `g = x + y`), you can use:

```py
factors = sympy.Mul.make_args(sympy.factor(g))
```

And to get back your expression from `factors` you can either use `sympy.Mul(*factors)`, or in a less hacky way:

```py
sympy.prod(factors)  # g.equals(this) should always evaluate to True
```