# sympy laurent polynomial factor

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I think there must be a simple answer to this, but I searched long and couldn't find it.

Example: A simple Laurent Polynomial, so that

`>> p = 2*y*x**2+4*y/x`

A factorization gives

`>> factor(p)
2*y*(x**3 + 2)/x`
How do I extract the factor `2*y/x` ? Is there a simple way to get the common factor in the expression when the expression isn't a polynomial? I have tried a lot, but haven't found anything remotely satisfying. The factorization must exist somewhere in the steps of `factor()`, right?

Comment: `factor(p).args` returns the top level terms in the product: `(2, y, 1/x, x**3 + 2)`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes!! thank you so much...

Comment: @unutbu not quite, because `factor_list` only works on polynomials proper, whereas `factor` is smart with rational functions and factors the numerator and denominator separately.

Answer (score 3):

As @unutbu points out, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248557/get-a-list-of-factors-in-sympy-factor) you can see that `factor_list` gives the factors of a polynomial in a easier to use fashon.

Unfortunately, SymPy doesn't actually deal with Laurent polynomials (see https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5131). You might actually not get what you are expecting for higher order terms. What SymPy does is it sees that `p` is a rational function, so it factors the numerator and denominator separately.

If you also want to do this, you can use something like

```
n, d = fraction(cancel(p))
factor_list(n)
factor_list(d)
```

and manipulate the factors separately.

The `cancel` will ensure that there are no duplicates, which would otherwise happen automatically with `factor(p)`, and it also puts the expression in rational form so that `fraction` will work. You could also use `p.as_numer_denom()` to skip this step (if it ends up being slow).

Alternately, you may want to consider `x` and `1/x` as separate generators of the polynomial. Here's a (corrected) function from the above issue

```
def aspoly1t(p, t, z=Symbol('z')):
    """
    Rewrite p, a polynomial in t and 1/t, as a polynomial in t and z=1/t
    """
    pa, pd = cancel(p).as_numer_denom()
    pa, pd = Poly(pa, t), Poly(pd, t)
    assert pd.is_monomial
    d = pd.degree(t)
    one_t_part = pa.slice(0, d + 1)
    t_part = pa - one_t_part
    t_part = t_part.to_field().quo(pd)
    one_t_part = Poly.from_list(reversed(one_t_part.rep.rep), *one_t_part.gens, domain=one_t_part.domain)
    one_t_part = one_t_part.replace(t, z) # z will be 1/t
    ans = t_part.as_poly(t, z) + one_t_part.as_poly(t, z)
    return ans
```

(some day Poly will support this natively as `Poly(p, x, 1/x)`) You can then use `factor_list` on this:

```
>>> aspoly1t(p, x)
Poly(2*y*x**2 + 4*y*z, x, z, domain='ZZ[y]')
>>> factor_list(aspoly1t(p, x))
(2, [(Poly(y, x, y, z, domain='ZZ'), 1), (Poly(x**2 + 2*z, x, y, z, domain='ZZ'), 1)])
```

Note that the factors here are not the same, so it really does matter how you want to interpret and factor your Laurent polynomials.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a more elegant solution. For the time being, I'll use a simple fix: I get the degree of the largest negative power using the `factor.args` and keeping this "shift" in mind when evaluating the polynomial coefficients obtained from `all_coeffs(Poly(px))`, where px is now the polynomial part.